# A generalization of Grunsky's theorem?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

There is an old theorem of Grunsky that an univalent holomorphic function on the unit disc in ${\mathbb C}$ maps a smaller disc (of radius $\tanh\pi/4$) onto a starlike region. Does anyone know about a generalization to a ball in ${\mathbb C}^n$?